# Если динамически добавлять js то его потом не удалить?

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка "А", при клике на которую jq обращается на сервер и сервер отдает строку html с скриптом VueJs. Скрипт VueJs при загрузке страницы выполняет какие либо действия. Если я ещё раз кликну на кнопку "А", то сначала удаляется загруженный html вместе со скриптом, а затем он снова подгружается с сервера и снова добавляется на html страницу, но скрипт VueJs уже выполняется 2 раза.

Как мне удалить html вместе с javascript кодом перед загрузкой с сервера новой строки содержащей html и VueJs?

У меня есть предположения, что я удаляю только HTML, но сам скрипт остается зарегистрированным...

Вот код с помощью которого осуществляется динамическое удаление и добавление html

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.replaceContentWith = function(newContent) {

        while (this.firstChild)
            this.removeChild(this.firstChild);

        this.html(newContent);
    };


})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Тяжело понять вопрос. Если Удаляемый HTML BLOCK содержит вложенный script, то при вызове метода removeChild()  блок будет удален вместе со всем содержимым, включая script. Возможно, если из скрипта, были по ссылке переданы какие либо объекты в другие части JS кода, то они останутся. По причине того, что были переданы по ссылке. Извините за пространственный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант присвоить функцию какой нибудь переменной, а при добавлении html очищать ее, например:

```
var code = function () {
//paste code here
};
code();
//...
code = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Моя проблема была именно в том,что я удалял элемент, вместо того, чтобы просто скрывать.

Если HTML который нам нужно подгрузить уже однажды был загружен, то мы не будем загружать его с сервера заново, а просто сделаем $('#target').show()

Убиваем сразу 2 зайцев. И проблема решается и не нужно лишний раз на сервер обращаться.

По сути кэширование на стороне клиента происходит в рамках сессии